# Invoking aws-lambda fun by node js and getting retured data. That lambda also invoking some other lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

Hi I have two lambda fun lambdaA and lambdaB in python. I am invoking lambdaB from lambdaA. lambdaB returns some data and I store the data in a variable in lambdaA.

Now the problem is:
I want that stored variable data by invoking lambdaA from node js.

Is it possible? Or any other solution to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but why not just returned the variable stored in lambda A?

Comment: The languages are irrelevant. You can invoke lambdaA from any language, and lambdaA/B can be implemented in any language. It makes no difference to what you need to do, i.e. return data from lambdaA.

Comment: Actually I haven't used lambda before. I have a doubt that suppose lambdaA hits lambdaB two times. I have set a global variable in lambdaB on the first hit. Will that variable persist on the second hit.